# Azure Queue Trigger Functions Not picking the queued message

Tags: azure, function, queuetrigger

The queue function is working fine in the developer machine. But once published to Azure, after a day or two, the function is not picking the queue message. the queue message is displayed in the Storage Account queue and not dequeued.

When we are using the Run command in monitor then it is picking the queue message and processing successfully.

For your Information: Not access issues, all application and id and secrets are correctly configured, all hosted in the same tenant, No exceptions generated.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I have a similar problem, but what worked for me when some function went to sleep was:

1. Regenerate the connection string.
2. Remove the resource (function) and create a new one.

I don't really know why sometimes some functions goes idle and then it no longer trigger.